# Shifting Summations and Integrals

Tags: summation, intuition, change-of-variable

When adding summations, for example, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 3x^{n - 1} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^n$, a variable change such as $m = n - 1$ is often made, in this case yielding $\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} 3x^m + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^n$.  Although the motivation to do so depends on this question having been answered, I'll break a term out of the first summation to match the indices, yielding $3 + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} 3x^m + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^n$.

The next step is to rename $m$ as $n$, and proceed to combine and factor the expression into $3 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (3 + n)x^n$.  This is the part that seems very unnatural to me.  The explanations I've heard to justify renaming $m$ as $n$ are "What does the name of a variable really matter? It's just a name!" and "$m$ and $n$ are just iteration variables that won't be present in the final expression."  Neither of these is very satisfying.  I get that it doesn't matter what name a variable has.  There is a very natural and obvious bijection between $r + 2 = 6$ and $y + 2 = 6$.  I even get that a variable name can be used multiple times in a problem.  You can use $A$ in an ODE system to represent both the coefficient matrix and an arbitrary constant, provided you keep the uses straight in your mind.  The problem here is that factoring step *doesn't* seem to keep the uses straight.  It treats old $n$ and new $n$ as the same variable.  The fact that $m$ and $n$ are iteration variables also doesn't seem to imply that they're the same variable; if values of $n$ represent days in a week ($n = 1$ is Sunday, $n = 2$ is Monday, etc.), then equivalent values of $m$ (or new $n$) represent *different* days (shifted by $1$).

I am not looking for an answer that expands a summation and its shifted version to prove that they match.  Also, I can do the algebra for a summation shift quickly with no problem, and it makes perfect sense at that level of abstraction.  It's only when I slow down and actually make the variable changes that things start to feel wrong.

Comment: Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two numbers defined on positive integers. Are you comfortable with the identity $\sum_{a=1}^\infty f(a) + \sum_{b=1}^\infty g(b) = \sum_{c=1}^\infty (f(c)+g(c))$? If not, there's the crux of your cognitive dissonance. If so, what happens if you change $a$ to $m$ and $b$ to $n$ and $c$ to $n$?

Comment: Another comment: forgetting the second series, these manipulations show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3x^{n-1} = 3 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3x^n$. You say something about $n$ being "the same [iteration] variable"; I think that trying to make sense of that phrase is actually causing confusion. Both sides are well-defined expressions, and they are equal; this has nothing to do with whether the $n$ on the left is the "same" as the $n$ on the right.

Comment: @GregMartin "Are you comfortable with the identity...?"  I'm going to say no.  Suppose $a$ and $b$ are discrete temporal variables ($b$ is a shifted version of $a$ defined as a substitution), $f(a)$ represents a husband's income over time, and $g(b)$ represents the wife's income over time.

Comment: If $a = 1$ represents $Jan. 1, 2000$, $a = 2$ represents $Jan. 2, 2000$, $a = 32$ represents $Feb. 1, 2000$, and so on to infinity, but $b = 1$ ($b$ being a shifted version of $a$) represents $Feb. 1, 2000$, $b = 2$ represents $Feb. 2, 2000$, and so on to infinity, then no matter how values of $c$ get mapped to dates, the partial sums of $∑_{c=1}^{\infty}(f(c) + g(c))$ cannot represent the total amount earned by the couple up to and including the input date.

Comment: "I'm going to say no [I'm not comfortable with the sum rule for infinite series]." Ok. Are you comfortable with the "limit law" for sums (stated and proven [on the Oxford College of Emory University site](http://math.oxford.emory.edu/site/math111/proofs/limitOfSum/))? And are you comfortable with [the definition of the sum of a series as a limit of partial sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Basic_properties)?

Comment: @MarkS. Yeah, those both look good.

Comment: @user10478, about your temporal example: I think the best thing I can say is that the mathematical expressions have an intrinsic meaning (that is, a definition) that is consistent with all of the adding series, shifting indices, and renaming variables that we're discussing. You've described one way of ascribing additional meaning to the variables and expressions, and you've observed that this additional meaning is not preserved under some of these operations, which is all fine ...

Comment: ... but the important thing is that your additional meaning is something you brought to the table, not something that's intrinsic to the mathematical expressions. Maybe there's a situation where the mathematical operation, while valid, wouldn't give you an expression that is consistent with the additional meaning. But that doesn't change the fact that it is a valid mathematical operation as far as the definitions of the mathematical objects are concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just explaining [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978219/shifting-summations-and-integrals?noredirect=1#comment8207992_3978219):

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions, and for each $n$, let $A_n={\displaystyle \sum_{a=1}^n} f(a)$, $B_n={\displaystyle \sum_{b=1}^n} g(b)$, and $C_n={\displaystyle \sum_{c=1}^n} \left(f(c)+g(c)\right)$.

Note that $C_n=(f(1)+g(1))+(f(2)+g(2))+\cdots+(f(n)+g(n))$, so that by [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) and [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of (finite) addition, $C_n=A_n+B_n$. Then by [limit laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties), ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}A_n+{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}B_n={\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}C_n$ whenever you know at least two of the limits exist (it's a sum law if you know the $A$ and $B$ limits exist, and it's a difference law otherwise).

However, by [the definition of the sum of a series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Basic_properties), this means that we have

$$\boxed{{\displaystyle \sum_{a=1}^\infty} f(a)+{\displaystyle \sum_{b=1}^\infty} g(b)={\displaystyle \sum_{c=1}^\infty} \left(f(c)+g(c)\right)\text{if two series converge}}\tag{$1$}$$

Writing $a$ as $m$ and $b$ as $n$ and $c$ as $n$, but keeping the uses straight (each $n$ appears in its own sum on its own side of the equation), we obtain

$$\boxed{{\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^\infty} f(m)+{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty} g(n)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty} \left(f(n)+g(n)\right)\text{if two series converge}}\tag{$2$}$$

But this says exactly that the step of "rename $m$ to $n$ and then combine the two series, treating the two $n$s the same" is mathematically valid*.

---

*But this is only guaranteed to work under the assumption that either: 1. both of the original $m$ and $n$ series converge. or 2. one of the $m$ and $n$ series converges, and the end result converges too.

For example, if we choose $f(m)=\dfrac{1}{2m-1}$ and $g(n)=-\dfrac{1}{2n}$, then the left side is undefined (it looks like the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$) but [the right side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) is $\ln2$.

For this sort of reason, you were right to be cautious. But, in practice, this issue doesn't come up often in calculations.