# Why can the "i" represent two different things simultaneously?

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yMxr.png)

Hi everyone, this question might be easy, but I'm still getting stuck.
Can anyone explain to me why the 'i' can represent two different things simultaneously? Thank you very much!

The question is from the book: *"A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross*.

**The binomial theorem**: $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

Proof of the Binomial Theorem by Induction: When n = 1, the Equation above reduces to
$$x+y= {1\choose 0}x^0y^1+{1\choose 1}x^1 y^0=y+x$$

Assume Equation for n − 1. Now,

$$(x+y)^n=(x+y)(x+y)^{n-1}=(x+y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k y^{n-1-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}x^{k+1}y^{n-1-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}x^k y^{n-k}$$

**My question is here:** Letting i=k+1 in the first sum and i=k in the second sum, we find that

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose i-1}x^i y^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose i}x^i y^{n-i}$$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Use $j$ in the second sum if you don't like $i$, it makes no difference.

Comment: You might find this question and the comments revealing (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978219/shifting-summations-and-integrals).  In short, if you're attributing certain intuitive meanings to sums of summations, the point you've raised might genuinely break the intuitive meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index variable $i$ is a so-called *[bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)*. This means that the scope (i.e. the range of validity) of the variable is determined by the sigma-operator $\sum$ and the *[operator precedence rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)*.

> The following representations are valid
> \begin{align*}
> (x+y)^n&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose i-1}x^i y^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose i}x^i y^{n-i}\\
> &=\left(\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose i-1}x^i y^{n-i}}\right)
> +\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose i}x^i y^{n-i}}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose i-1}x^i y^{n-i}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}x^k y^{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we present the scope of each of the index variables somewhat more clearly by using parenthesis and the colors green and blue.
- In (2) we denote the index variable of the right-most sum with $k$.

*Hint:* It is often convenient to give different index variables different names, even if they have no overlapping scope. This usually enhances readability.

*Note:* We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k&=a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k-1}=\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{j-2}
\end{align*}
The index shift at the sigma symbol $\sum$ is compensated at each occurrence of the index variable *within the scope* of the symbol. The index name $k, j, \ldots$ is not relevant, since it denotes always the right-hand sum at (3).

Comment: Thank you all for answering it. But I want to be more specific about the question as follows:



How to go from this line:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}x^{k+1}y^{n-1-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}x^k y^{n-k}$$

to this line:

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose i-1}x^i y^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose i}x^i y^{n-i}$$

Comment: And If I replace the right-most sum with another dummy variable, how can I utilize Pascal's rule in the next step, thank you!

Comment: @Victor: You're welcome. I've added a note which might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, @epi163sqrt! 
Finally, I got it, so the bound variables, k, i, or j, don't matter at all.

Comment: @Victor: Yes, correct! :-)